# How to perform the function, after all crawling is done in scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

spider_closed() function is not performing. If i give just print statement it is printing but if i perform any function call and return the value it is not working.

```
import scrapy
import re
from pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals

from SouthShore.items import Product
from SouthShore.internalData import internalApi
from scrapy.http import Request

class bestbuycaspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bestbuy_dca"

    allowed_domains = ["bestbuy.ca"]

    start_urls = ["http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+beds",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+night+stand",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+headboard",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+desk",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+bookcase",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+dresser",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+tv+stand",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+armoire",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+kids",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+changing+table",
              "http://www.bestbuy.ca/Search/SearchResults.aspx?type=product&page=1&sortBy=relevance&sortDir=desc&pageSize=96&query=south+shore+furniture+baby"]

    def __init__(self,jsondetails="",serverdetails="", *args,**kwargs):
        super(bestbuycaspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        self.jsondetails = jsondetails
        self.serverdetails=serverdetails
        self.data = []

    def parse(self,response):
        #my stuff here 



    def spider_closed(self,spider):
        print "returning values"
        self.results['extractedData']=self.data
        print self.results=internalApi(self.jsondetails,self.serverdetails)
        yield self.results
```

1) I want to call some function and return the scraped values

Comment: so you want to keep crawling in `spider_closed`? yielding items or requests?

Comment: No , i want to return the crawled items after spider is closed and call one more function in another py file, so it will do some operations  and give some values. I need to append and return, my crawled values and that called function output together.

Comment: scrapy items are not stored in memory, they are outputted when you call `yield item`. If you want to process every item as it outputs, you'll have to use a pipeline, but using ALL of them once the spider ends is a really bad practice (because you'll have to store them yourself)

Answer (score 4):

You can create an [Item Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) with `close_spider()` method:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def close_spider(self, spider):
        do_something_here()
```

Just don't forget to activate it in settings.py as described in the docummentation link above.

Comment: Apologizes, I,m new to scrapy,  do i need to create Pipeline class  & closs_spider function in  pipelines.py file or can i change the class name in my spider file itself.

Comment: If i need to create class & function in pipelines.py file, so my  doubts are         1) How can i  import that pipeline class to my spider file or will take automatically?                                                                                                     2) how to pass the crawled values to the close_spider function which is in pipelines.y file.